# How to create a ComponentView for an Element in javax.swing.text.HtmlDocument

Tags: java, swing, view, custom-component, dom

Maybe my question it's a little weird, but I'm trying to build a not-so-simple html editor and I need to provide the users, the capability of modify divs over the document. I already done some custom tags and other few things, but this time I'm really stuck because it's a little different:

I just dont know how to build a View for my element that I can put on somewhere freely over the interface of editor and at the same time, it allows modify the document on the current Element position.

So, I want something like:

```
 <html>
   ...
   <body>
       <div style="position:absolute; left:80px; bottom:0px;" >My Div</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I've builded, first at all, a FloatingView class, that extends ComponentView, and put it on the editor layout, so I can freely move it around, and on his component, I added a new JTextPane, but synchronize it's a nightmare, because, I dont know how to do it or if I'm doing it on the wrong way.

Please, if some one knows some document or page where I can get a base to start over, I really appreciate it so much.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this 
http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html as a basement of your editor.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already done some of work using your post, thanks a lot.